# XSLT: Add name space, copy content, change value of copied content

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have an XML I would like to do some transformations on which I can't seem to get to work in Java. Below I have provided the input, desired output and my attempt. I do not know what I'm doing wrong here, any help is appreciated.

To summarize, I want to basically do three transformations:

1. Add declaration of new namespace.
2. Change the version number.
3. Move certain elements into the new namespace.

My guess is there is something wrong when I do the copy. Maybe after copy I am overwriting something.

**This is my input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Structure xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/Structure"
                            version="2.0"
                            name="myName">

  <Graph name="test">

    <Vertices>
      <Vertex name="n1" kind="input"/>
      <Vertex name="n2" kind="output"/>
    </Vertices>

    <Edges>
      <Edge start="n1" end="n2">
        <Transformation>
          <Entry entry="1"/>
        </Transformation>
      </Edge>
    </Edges>

  </Graph>

</Structure>
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Structure xmlns:cs="http://www.example.com/xsd/ControlStructure"
xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/Structure" version="3.0"
name="myName">            <--- Declared name space and changed version

  <Graph name="test">

    <Vertices>
      <Vertex name="n1" kind="input"/>
      <Vertex name="n2" kind="output"/>
    </Vertices>

    <Edges>
      <Edge start="n1" end="n2">
        <cs:Transformation>                 <--- Added name space
          <Entry entry="1"/>
        </cs:Transformation>                <--- Added name space
      </Edge>
    </Edges>

  </Graph>

</Structure>
```

**This is my XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    <xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

    <xsl:param name="cs" select="'http://www.example.com/xsd/ControlStructure'"/>

    <!-- copy everything into the output -->
    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Declare new name space -->
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Structure']">
        <Structure xmlns:cs="http://www.example.com/xsd/ControlStructure>"
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
        </Structure>
    </xsl:template>  


    <!-- Upgrade version attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="node()[local-name()='Structure']/@version">
      <xsl:attribute name="version">
        <xsl:value-of select="'3.0'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Move all *Transformation elements to the cs namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="node()[contains(local-name(), 'Transformation')]">
      <xsl:element name="cs:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The `xsl:copy-of` inside of the template with `match="/*[local-name()='Structure']"` should be an `xsl:apply-templates`, otherwise the rest of the input is simply copied and your other templates are never used/applied.

Comment: I tried changing as you suggested but does not solve the problem. I get "ERROR:  'Namespace for prefix 'cs' has not been declared.' ". 

If I delete the last section containing the lines with "Transformation", so to focus just on updating the version I can ignore the error temporarily. However, the version is still "2.0" and not "3.0", so I can't even update the version.

Comment: Your XSLT is using an `xsl:param` for the namespace. Does that mean you want to vary what the output namespace will be, or will it always be "http://www.example.com/xsd/ControlStructure"?

Comment: It will always be "example.com/xsd/ControlStructure". Still, if I ignore all the namespace stuff and just focus and changing the version I still get no effect so something else is also wrong.

Comment: With the proposed change and when removing the question of the <Transformation> element, then the resulting XSLT code should be replacing the version with 3.0. If that doesn't work for you, we'll need you to update the entirety of the code you've shown, completely as-is with a copy/paste. (I know your question contains no cpoy/paste of a code you've run, because the XML is malformed. That's not good. Only work with copy/pastes of the code you've tried and run yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a parameter cs bound to the new namespace, which you aren't using. It's not clear whether you really want the new namespace to be a run-time parameter, or whether it can be hard-coded. If you want it to be a parameter, then your best bet is to switch to an XSLT 2.0 processor and use xsl:namespace.

Otherwise, you're on the right lines.

Your template to change the version attribute has no effect because it never fires: that's because your template for the Structure element copies attributes unchanged, rather than applying templates to them.

In the instruction `<xsl:element name="cs:{local-name()}">` you should add a `namespace` attribute to define the new namespace URI. Otherwise it looks for a binding of the prefix "cs" in the stylesheet, and there isn't one. It's not enough for it to have a binding in the result tree.

Comment: The parameter cs is not necessary and could be hard coded.

Could you perhaps provide some example code regarding how to change the version and how to add the namespace attribute?

Comment: In the template for Structure elements, change `xsl:copy-of` to `xsl:apply-templates`. In `<xsl:element name="cs:{local-name()}">`, add `namespace="http://www.example.com/xsd/ControlStructure"`